# Get Doctrine Exception to Log

Tags: symfony, exception, doctrine, symfony5

Sorry but, I have a big problem, in a project I have to make some Cron Task where I add or edit some data in my Database and I want to get back the Doctrine error message if there is a problem.

[Try Catch Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rOZV.png)

[Error I want to get back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC3I5.png)

[Monolog Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bovPb.png)

[Monolog Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw4YV.png)

Comment: Hi. Use monolog. https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html

Answer (score 0):

As @alexcm says, you could use Monolog. Here is an example autoinjecting it in a service.

This will save the message in the log file, make sure what exception level are you saving in the logs file.

```
private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    
    public function add(TypeConges $entity, bool $flush = true): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);
        if ($flush) {
            try {
                $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
                print($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it didn't log... I'm in dev Mode and in this mode i have log in dev.log and in console, but in prod mode it didn't work ...

```
try{
            $this->congeeRepository->add($congee);
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            $this->logger->info("Test : ".$e->getMessage());
            print("Test2 : ".$e->getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: could you please attach how monolog.yml is defined?

Comment: I attached is the post thanks!